# How to give write permission to apache on all files

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2, debian

I need to give write permission to apache on all my files, I checked apache user in config file and with exec("whoami"), it's www-data, but if I had www-data to root group apache isn't able to write a file. I tried to set run-group as root and restart apache, but nothing change. How can I do to give this permission to apache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your should check what kind of permission level you want.
A good way to go is to give write permissions only for folders where you need it.

check that your www-data user is at least in the group of the access group or change the it:

`chgrp -R www-data folder/`

then set the write permissions with

`chmod -R g+w folder`

should be enough

Comment: root group wasn't able to writes :-/ my bad, thinked root group get all permissions on anything, ty for your help